# How to modal body text responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I send text from js to modal but the text_description element in modal body is not responsive

---

Picture Modal
[image: h]

HTML

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="" id="viewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="viewMModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="viewMModalLabel">Description</h5>
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="text_description">ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add this CSS `word-break: break-all:` on `#text_description`

Comment: What do you want to happen when the text overflows the modal? Truncate the text, make it wrap to the next line? Also can you post the css you use for the `modal-body` and `text_description`?

Comment: That is more of a line drawn with several s. If you fit a normal sentence in there it is going to be responsive without you needing word-wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Change `overflow-wrap` to `break-word` for `text_description`.

```css
#text_description {
  overflow-wrap:break-word;
}
```

What this does is adjusts different words so that they do not break in the middle and wraps long words onto the next line.

```css
#text_description {
  overflow-wrap: break-word
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="" id="viewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="viewMModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="viewMModalLabel">Description</h5>
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="text_description">ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="" id="viewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="viewMModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="viewMModalLabel">Description</h5>
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="text_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

OR use the bootstrap's `.text-truncate` class to hide long text

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class=" " id="viewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="viewMModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="viewMModalLabel">Description</h5>
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="text_description" class="text-truncate">ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use simple CSS `word-break: break-all;`. See demo below

```css
.modal-body {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the other answers also works, but you can add bootstrap class `text-break` to the text which will work the same way, so you don't have to add additional css style

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewModal">
  Launch modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="viewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="viewMModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="viewMModalLabel">Description</h5>
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="text_description" class="text-break">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
            Launch demo modal
          </button>

          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">
                  ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Use **overflow-wrap: break-word;** on **.modal-body** class

Comment: Your snippet fails for continious text https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JQmQdN

Comment: Sorry for that, edited the snippets. 
Also used overflow-wrap: break-word on modal-body.